# Where is the google app engine source code root

Tags: google-app-engine, google-console-developer

Where is the google app engine home root? I can't seem to find it, I want to edit the source code in there but I just can't. I want to  use the default editor but I just can't seem to find the root project or wherever it is that's located at. Do you know where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is only possible if you are using **App Engine Flex**.

For **App Engine Flex** the deployment gets your files, build a Docker container with them, and then deploys this container inside a VM. As you can see on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance), you can connect directly to your container by running:

```
gcloud app instances ssh [INSTANCE-NAME] --service [SERVICE] --version [VERSION] 
docker exec -it gaeapp /bin/bash
```

Once you run these commands you will be on the root folder of your container and changes you make on files will be reflected on the current running version of your app.

If you are using **App Engine Standard**, you cannot access the instances since it is a fully managed environment. Therefore you won't be able to find the root of the running app version.

**NOTE**: For **App Engine Standard**, since it uses a staging bucket to gather the code before compiling, you are able to get the files themselves but on a pre deployment state, meaning that if you change them it will not reflect on the current running version of your app. You can find your staging bucket through the App Engine Admin API. This bucket is usually `staging.<PROJECT_ID>.appspot.com`, although you can change this configuration.

Comment: So that's where I was failing at. I just have the standard one. Thank you for the answer, I wasn't totally aware of this. I'm guessing I'll have to change the service or re upload everything. Thank you very much!